# Catel/WPF performance while switching view

Tags: wpf, devexpress, catel

I have problem with view switching performance on my application.

I have a Module which has pre-created View and ViewModel like:

```
public void InitializeModule()
{
    this.Presenter = ViewHelper.ConstructViewWithViewModel<TView>(typeof(TView), new TViewModel());
    this.ViewModel = (TViewModel)this.Presenter.DataContext;
}
```

Then, I'm displaying it on a screen via ActiveView like:

```
<ContentPresenter
      Margin="0"
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
      Content="{Binding ActiveView.Presenter}" />
```

The problem is, that there is a lag between activating view and showing it.

Changing view is just replacing ActiveView with another pre-created Module.

I have checked, that constructor of View and ViewModel is running only once. And there's no big logic between these changing.

Could you please tell me what could be a cause of it? It looks very crappy when I have a lag ~0.2s while switching to another view.

**//Edit:**

Lag is existing on every Module. It seems to be longer on more complicated views (i.e. with DevExpress controls)

**Edit2:**
I have profiled my application and seems that the longest loading module, which contains DevExpress Scheduler has a hot-spot at these methods:

```
DevExpress.Xpf.Scheduler.Drawing.SharedSizePanel.MeasureOverrideCore()
DevExpress.Xpf.Core.DXBorder.MeasureOverride()
```

Is there a way to reduce it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this has probably to do with the DevExpress controls measuring how much space they have and how much space they want. Try to use this with empty views that are still using Catel. If so, then enable detailed logging in Catel using `LogManager.AddDebugListener()` to check the logging.

If the issue goes away, there can be 2 reasons:

1. You are running a very complex visual tree (then it might be smarter to play with visibility instead of replacing the whole content of the display region).
2. DevExpress controls have an issue (might be misconfigured?). Then it's best to contact their support.

Comment: Changed way to showing/collapsing different views works well. Thanks